# How do I suppress PC-Lint errors for C99-style initialization of structure members?

Tags: c, c99, lint, pc-lint

I am using PC-Lint 8.00x with the following options:

`+v -wlib(1) +fan +fas`

I receive a number of error messages from PC-Lint when I run code similar to the following:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int a : 4;
        unsigned int b : 4;
        unsigned int c : 4;
        unsigned int d : 4;
    } bits;
    unsigned short value;
} My_Value;

int main (void)
{
    My_Value test[] =
    {
        {
            .bits.a = 2,
            .bits.b = 3,    //Errors 133 and 10
            .bits.c = 2,
            .bits.d = 3,
        },
        {
            .bits.a = 1,
            .bits.b = 1,    //Errors 133 and 10
            .bits.c = 1,
            .bits.d = 0,
        },
    };

    /* Do something meaningful. */

    return 0;
}
```

The reported errors are defined by PC-Lint as follows:

> > Error 133: Too many initializers for aggregate 'unknown-name'
> >
> > Error 10: Expecting '}'

I have tried searching Gimpel and have done some Google searches, but I cannot find anything useful.  The code functions as intended and everything initializes properly.  Here are my questions.

**1. Does PC-Lint 8.00x support C99 style initialization of structure members?**

**2. If so, what options/flags do I have to set for PC-Lint to suppress these messages globally?**

**EDIT**
I should have been more detailed in regards to question 2.  I would like to globally suppress these messages in regards to my usage of designated initializers as shown above.  I cannot suppress them globally for all situations as these errors can detect true errors in the code.

Comment: I don't know if nesting the member fields like that (e.g. `.bits.a`) is really okay. I would suspect you need to do e.g. `My_value test[] = { { { .a = 2, .b = 3, .c = 2, .d = 3 } }, ... }`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's a good point.  I have seen some examples of using a designated initializer list to initialize nested structs (like [this](http://http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdesignators.htm)), but I do not know for certain if this is proper C99.  I may need to open another question...

Comment: It appears that my usage of a designated initializer list as written above is valid.  However, I still can't get PC-Lint to play nice with this particular implementation.

Comment: I agree that it's valid; the grammar permits a *designator-list*, and `.bits.a` qualifies (and gcc and clang both accept it). But what happens if you move the `.bits` up a level?

Comment: @KeithThompson, It looks like you are onto something.  If I change to `[0].bits.a = 1` and continue through `[1].bits.d = 0` PC-Lint doesn't complain anymore and armcc still compiles it correctly.  That may be my best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this syntax:

```
My_Value test[] =
{
    {
        .bits.a = 2,
        .bits.b = 3,
        .bits.c = 2,
        .bits.d = 3,
    },
    {
        .bits.a = 1,
        .bits.b = 1,
        .bits.c = 1,
        .bits.d = 0,
    },
};
```

is valid in C99 (and C11). Looking in section 6.7.8 of the standard, the thing preceding the `=` in an initializer is a *designator-list*, which is a sequence of one or more *designator*s. `.bits.a` is valid in that context.

Apparently PC-Lint doesn't support that syntax. (You might want to notify the maintainers, unless it's already supported in a later version.)

As a workaround, if you change it to this:

```
My_Value test[] =
{   
    { .bits =
        {   
            .a = 2,
            .b = 3,
            .c = 2,
            .d = 3,
        },
    },
    { .bits =
        {   
            .a = 1,
            .b = 1,
            .c = 1,
            .d = 0,
        },
    },
};
```

it's still valid C (and arguably clearer) and, based on what you just wrote in a comment, PC-Lint accepts it.

(If you want to be even more explicit, you might consider adding `[0] =` and `[1] =` designators.)

**UPDATE :** QUoting a new commment:

> The good people at Gimpel software have responded stating that "this
>   appears to be a bug" and are working to correct it.

Comment: PC-Lint 9.00k has no issues with the second form posted above. I'd go with this.

Comment: Spot on, I just verified with 8.00x and PC-Lint is happy and it still conveys the original intention of the code.  Thanks, Keith and thanks @SimeonPilgrim for breathing new life into a question that I thought would remain unanswered.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim and Keith, The good people at Gimpel software have responded stating that "this appears to be a bug" and are working to correct it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to the C99 and 8.00x support question, as I have 9.00k installed. But 9.00k dislikes your form of union initialization, but Visual Studio has no issue.

But for Jacchim Pileborg's case it just emits a `Info 708: union initialization` while might be safer to turn off.

As noted in the comments you dont want to fully globally remove these error types, so `-e133` and `-e10` will not solve your problems.

So using Joachim's form, I can using a macro suppress it like so:

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int a : 4;
        unsigned int b : 4;
        unsigned int c : 4;
        unsigned int d : 4;
    } bits;
    unsigned short value;
} My_Value;

#define MY_UNION(A,B,C,D) /*lint -save -e708*/{{.a=(A),.b=(B),.c=(C),.d=(D)}}/*lint -restore*/

int main(void)
{
    My_Value test[] =
    {
        MY_UNION(2, 3, 2, 1),
        MY_UNION(1, 2, 3, 4)
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Ugly, but as you have nothing to make the lint commands to stick to as it's all anonymous, you ether have to put inline commands explicitly or via a macro.

Comment: Thanks, Simeon.  I suppose I should have been more detailed about question number 2.  I would like to suppress those messages globally as they apply to this particular situation.  However, both of those errors can be potentially useful so I do not want them disabled for all situations.  That's interesting that 9.00k does not like @JoachimPileBorg and my initializations...  Either one of which should work under C99. +1

Comment: @embedded_guy 9.00k does not complain about this as bad, but it does have an `info 708` which would be safer to supress, or suppress file by file.

The real issue is that what your doing is not really a class of thing (other than the 708 union initialization) thus you cannot suppress this instance everywhere. Now you could put into a MACRO then suppress those errors for that symbol.

Comment: The macro option is worth considering.  Although my manager has decided that it is unacceptable to have *any* lint comments in the code base, hence the desire to suppress globally.  However, I may be able to get around that by adding `-emacro(708, MY_UNION)` to my `options.lnt` file.