# Is it valid to use a C99-style designated initializer list to initialize the members of a bit field within a union in the following way?

Tags: c, c99

When I wrote a [question regarding PC-Lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823277/how-do-i-suppress-pc-lint-errors-for-c99-style-initialization-of-structure-membe), I had made an assumption that the following initialization is valid in C99.  @JoachimPileborg mentioned that it may not be and I haven't been able to find any information that provides a good example one way or another.  I know that it compiles and behaves as I expect, I would just like to know for certain that it is proper C99 code.

**Is this a valid way to initialize the following union in C99?**

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned int a : 4;
        unsigned int b : 4;
        unsigned int c : 4;
        unsigned int d : 4;
    } bits;
    unsigned short value;
} My_Value;

int main (void)
{
    My_value test[] =
    {
        {
            .bits.a = 2,
            .bits.b = 3,
            .bits.c = 2,
            .bits.d = 3,
        },
        {
            .bits.a = 1,
            .bits.b = 1,
            .bits.c = 1,
            .bits.d = 0,
        },
    };

    /* Do something meaningful. */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks sane... if your tame compiler doesn't complain with standards compliance cranked *way* up, I'd use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks sane... if your tame compiler doesn't complain with standards compliance cranked *way* up, I'd use it. Much more worrying is that you presumably are trying to overlay `value` and `bits`, and stuffing data into one alternative of an union an taking it out of the other is *undefined*. Endianness aside, the union will probably use up a full word, and very well could have the `value` at one end and the `bits` at the other (depending on available instructions and their convenience or timing). The standards declare this undefined precisely to give implementations such leeway.

Comment: It's no longer undefined.  It was undefined in C89, but C99 states that the value is now "unspecified".  See defect report #257.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, OK. It won't start nethack anymore, but you still can't depend on it "doing what I consider sane today"...